# Inline code being taken as ASPX code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp TextBox control named "txtNewSubComment". However, because I am dynamically generating multiple of the same textboxes, I need a way to keep them unique so I can reference them. I'm trying to do the following:

`<asp:TextBox ID="txtNewSubComment_<%=comment.Id %>" />` (not the whole code chunk but you get the idea)

comment.Id would return a unique int which is related to that TextBox control. My problem is that aspx does not seem to read the inline code (<% %>) as inline code, but reads it as aspx instead. So instead of it being rendered in html as `txtNewSubComment_1` (if I managed to get to that stage without errors getting in the way) it is rendered as `txtNewSubComment_<%=comment.Id%>`

I have the problem when trying to pass in a CommandArgument for a button

The textboxes are generated via the following code within the aspx markup:

```
<%  Site.BO.Comment[] commentList = db.GetAllCommentsForImage(CurrentImage.Id);
                if (commentList.Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (Site.BO.Comment comment in commentList.OrderByDescending(x => x.LastUpdated))
                    {
                        Site.BO.Profile commenterProfile = db.ProfileGet(comment.User.Id); %>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewSubComment_<%=comment.Id %>" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>

<% } } %>
```

Comment: How are you creating them dynamically?  Are they in a repeater/grid?

Comment: They are generated in a foreach loop within the aspx code.

Comment: Is it possible to put them in a repeater, you're going to save yourself a number of headaches.

Comment: decorate it with `runat="server"`

Comment: Any ideas? OP has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.Net 4.0 Microsoft introduced ability to control how IDs are generated:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You are looking at `ClientIDMode` set to `Predictable`.

the control itself should contain `runat="server"` attribute

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptMeetings" DataSourceID="CommentsList" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewSubComment_<%# this.Eval("Id") %>" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" ClientIDMode="Predictable"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: based on your updated question, this should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211583/is-there-a-problem-using-scriptlet-tags-for-aspx-page
you may consider dynamic creation of controls; a repeater control or databinding to the datasource with your Ids

Answer (score -1):

If you are creating the text boxes in the code behind, you will NOT want the string to look like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNewSubComment_<%=comment.Id %>" />
```

You would want something like this:

```
Dim _value = 1
Dim _textBoxString2 As String = "<asp:TextBox ID=""" + _value + """/>"
```

Without seeing where/how you create the text boxes it will be hard to find a solution. You may want to post that as well.

Comment: Original post edited, should help. Also it's c# as the code-behind, not vb.net.